# Routing key does not match but still message gets sent to queue

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

Im trying to get rabbit to send round robin messages to different topics.
I have 1 queue called "endpoint/1"
I am dispatching messages to "endpoint/1" and "endpoint/2". "endpoint/2" does not exists so i expected those messages to disappear but instead they get sent to the queue "endpoint/1" event though there is no binding to it!

I have no idea why this is happening, am i doing something wrong?

[image]
[image]

```
// declare exchange
ch.ExchangeDeclare("uop_fanout", "fanout", false, false, false, false, nil)

//send
ch.Publish("uop_fanout", topic, false, false, amqp.Publishing{Body: msg})

// listend
q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(topic, false, false, false, false, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = ch.QueueBind(q.Name, topic, "uop_fanout", false, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    messagesFanout, err := ch.Consume(q.Name, "", false, false, false, false, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this statement:

```
ch.ExchangeDeclare("uop_fanout", "fanout", false, false, false, false, nil)
```

you are declaring an exchange of type `fanout`. This means messages arriving at the exchange get cloned and sent to *all* the queues bound to that exchange.

It's not clear what you mean by "round robin messages to different topics".

If you want to do just round-robin load balancing, you can simply route your messages to a single queue, and have two or more consumers for that queue.

If you want to distribute messages by topic, you can use a `direct` exchange, with specific routing keys. An arriving message will be sent to the queue bound with the matching routing key.

Of course, you can combine those concepts.

Source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html